# Executing two INSERT an the same stored procedure with a SCOPE_IDENTITY

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to insert a record into my SQL Server database with a stored procedure and
catch the ID of this inserted row (SCOPE_IDENTITY()) to use it in another insert command.

Because I would like to execute those two select command the one after the other if the one didn't pass the other didn't pass too !

Any Idea ?

Thank you for helping me !

Comment: I think your question is bit confusing. You are trying to insert a row into a table and then insert another row in some other table using the auto generated id in the first insert, and then select both the rows from both the tables? is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
DECLARE @NewID INT

INSERT INTO dbo.FirstTable(Col1, Col2, ...., ColN)
   VALUES(Value1, Value2, ....., ValueN)

SELECT @NewID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO dbo.SecondTable(IDColumn, ColA, ColB, .., ColZ)
  VALUES(@NewID, ValueA, ValueB, ...., ValueZ)
```

That should insert the first set of data into `dbo.FirstTable`, grab the newly created ID into `@NewID` and then insert the second batch of data using that new ID value.